# How can i create token based login form in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, jwt

i have create login form using session but now i want to create token based login form.
i have research a lot and i found JWT and Auth token based form.
But all examples were on MVC or CORE but i want create on simple webform.

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: Kindly post your code/error.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I don't have code beacuse i was just thinking about create login form without session.